# change background colour of notepad++ editor

Tags: colors, editor, notepad++

I knew that colour can be set through

Settings->Style Configurator

but when the line that I am editing has a different font and background colour which I don't know how to set.

Also when I am selecting an block of code, I can't control the colour of the selection.

Basically I just want to set the editor to have the same color as the typical console, green on black background (which is friendly to eyes, not straining).

Is it possible to customise the color in the notepad++ editor ?

Or anyone knows of an editor that can meet this requirement ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For me it works fine to do the following:
Go to "Settings" Menu and choose "Style Configurator".
There you choose "Global Styles" (language list) and "Default Style" (style list) and set the colors you want.

You can also try to use the "Global override" style and check the different checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++ there is quick option without change color setting. In Notepad++ have many themes with different color option.

Notepad++ has many themes which you can select in a dropdown box in the Style Configurator window. Many of these themes (e.g. Bespin, Black board, Twilight) have dark background and different colors for different kinds of text for programming languages.

[image]

After Click “Save & Close” Button then Background and Font Color will change, like in the below image.

[image]

more information [click here](http://www.thecodedeveloper.com/change-background-font-color-notepad/)

Comment: Unfortunately, this only affects the document, not the full theme of the entire application.